# How to assign integer value after split to certain childs of el?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html:

```
<div class="alm-filter alm-filter--meta" id="alm-filter-1" data-key="meta" data-fieldtype="checkbox" data-meta-key="Cate" data-meta-compare="IN" data-meta-type="CHAR">
   <ul>
     <li class="alm-filter--checkbox"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alm-filter--link field-checkbox field-other" id="checkbox-other-1" data-type="checkbox" data-value="other">Other</a></li>
     <li class="alm-filter--checkbox"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alm-filter--link field-checkbox field-painting active" id="checkbox-painting-1" data-type="checkbox" data-value="painting">Painting</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="alm-filter alm-filter--meta" id="alm-filter-2" data-key="meta" data-fieldtype="checkbox" data-meta-key="usp-custom-14" data-meta-compare="BETWEEN" data-meta-type="NUMERIC">
   <ul>
     <li class="alm-filter--checkbox"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alm-filter--link field-checkbox field-1900 active" id="checkbox-1900-2" data-type="checkbox" data-value="1900">1900</a></li>
     <li class="alm-filter--checkbox"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="alm-filter--link field-checkbox field-1920" id="checkbox-1920-2" data-type="checkbox" data-value="1920">1920</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to change the values eg. `field-1900` `id="checkbox-1900-2"` `data-value="1900"` with the values I receive from a `form` in another page. On the result page I do:

```
<?php $myId = $_POST['myDates']; ?>
```

And then the **js**:

```
var str = "<?php echo $myId; ?>";
var temp = new Array();
// this will return an array with strings "1", "2", etc.
temp = str.split(",");
for (a in temp ) {
  temp[a] = parseInt(temp[a], 10); // Explicitly include base
  $("#alm-filter-2").find("a").attr("value", temp[a]);
}
```

The above JS is an attempted logic, basically I know I have 2 elements containing different values I want to change, and I know I will get the `var` with 2 numbers: `var str = "1952,1991";`

How can I change the values of those two `a`s to reflect the values I am getting from the form?

**UPDATE**

This is getting closer:

```
var str = "<?php echo $myId; ?>";
var temp = new Array();
// this will return an array with strings "1", "2", etc.
temp = str.split(",");
temp = temp.map(Number);
$("#alm-filter-2").find("ul>:first-child a").attr("value", temp[0]);
```

But I need to change the `values` on all three cases and for all the `els a` reflecting the two values I get from the form.

Comment: Do you mean change the `data-value`? An `<a>` has no value. Also change text?

Comment: @EricNail `val()` is only for form controls not elements like `<a>`

Comment: @charlietfl hi, if you see the two `a` they have both `class`, `data-attribute` and `id`, with some number values like `field-1900` `id="checkbox-1900-2"` `data-value="1900"` and I need to change those numbers (1900 in this case) with what I get from the form var, one has to reflect one number form the `split` and the other the other one

Comment: @charlietfl updated the question but not there yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved taking part of an answer by @charlietfl

In the backend I set 1900 as the default values which I will change and then do:

```
var str = "<?php echo $myId; ?>";
var values = new Array();
values = str.split(",");
values = values.map(Number);
$("#alm-filter-2 a[data-value]").each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('data-value', values[i]);
  $(this).attr('id', function(_, currentID) {
     return currentID.replace('1900', values[i]);
  });
  $(this).attr('class', function(_, currentClass) {
     return currentClass.replace('1900', values[i]);
  });
  $(this).html(values[i]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Might as well explode the data first into array

```
var values = "<?php echo json_encode(explode(',',$myId)); ?>";
```

Then use `each` to loop over the elements and use their index to get each value from same index in array

```
$("#alm-filter-2 a[data-value]").each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('data-value', values[i]))
})
```

Comment: that's close but we have cases like the class which says `field-1900` and the id `id="checkbox-1900-2"` which have strings `field-` and `checkbox--2` and we need to replace the number there `1900`

Comment: What do you have in the server side data that can be used to match with elements?

Comment: nothing I'm afraid.. I must set those values as temp and then be able to change them via the DOM on document ready taking values from that php var, so there is a need of a string replace but how can we get that number within those strings?

Comment: Don't the `name`s in other form help? You aren't really showing enough to build relationships with

Comment: nope.. they are not related, I only use the form to send these values, but actually.. since `1900` and `1920` are a default number.. I could do a `string search` and replace like look for `1900` and replace it with `values[i]` ok that's the logic, but how to? ha!

Comment: ok I have provided my own answer, taking part of what you provided, thanks